# puppeteer evaluate does not return array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do web scraping, I got the data that I expecting to get but not as an array as I expected. I tried several ways but I end getting the same results. I know I'm making mistake somewhere, that is why I don't get as an array. Could anyone help me please. Here is my code

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const url = "https://perfumeonline.ca/collections/womens-cologne-clearnce-sales";
    await page.goto(url);

    const perfumes = await page.evaluate(() => 
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#centerCol > div > div:nth-child(1)"))
    .map(perfume => ({
        Sale : perfume.querySelector('div.product__label.product__label--left.product__label').innerHTML,
        image: perfume.querySelector('div.product__inside__image img').src,
        imape_path: perfume.querySelector('div.product__inside__image a').getAttribute('href'),
        product_title: perfume.querySelector('div.product__inside__name h2.product_title').innerHTML,
        brand_name: perfume.querySelector('h4.barnd-name').textContent.trim(),
        gender: perfume.querySelector('span.title-type').textContent.trim(),
        size: perfume.querySelector('h5.av-size').textContent.trim(),
        price: perfume.querySelector('div.product__inside__price.price-box > span:nth-child(1) > span').textContent.trim()
    }))
  );


    console.log(perfumes)

    await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: Format your code in a good way put it inside 3 grave accent from the top and 3 grave accent at the end

Answer (score 0):

Running the code, i get an array with a single item in it.

If you remove the `:nth-child(1)` it will return all elements. But you will have to account for some perfumes that are not on sale.

So using the [`?.` (*optional chaining operator*)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) you can avoid errors in the extraction

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#centerCol > div > div"))
.map(perfume => ({
    Sale : perfume.querySelector('div.product__label.product__label--left.product__label')?.innerHTML,
    image: perfume.querySelector('div.product__inside__image img')?.src,
    imape_path: perfume.querySelector('div.product__inside__image a')?.getAttribute('href'),
    product_title: perfume.querySelector('div.product__inside__name h2.product_title')?.innerHTML,
    brand_name: perfume.querySelector('h4.barnd-name')?.textContent.trim(),
    gender: perfume.querySelector('span.title-type')?.textContent.trim(),
    size: perfume.querySelector('h5.av-size')?.textContent.trim(),
    price: perfume.querySelector('div.product__inside__price.price-box > span:nth-child(1) > span')?.textContent.trim()
}))
```

---

if on the other hand you mean the the log is `[object Object]` then try `console.log(JSON.stringify(perfumes))`

Comment: Yes I get an array of single item, I'm looking to get multiple items not single